# Amazon MWS - How can we update the inventory on Amazon instantly?

Tags: amazon-mws

I was wondering if there is any way to update inventory instantly on Amazon by using MWS.

We are having the issue, when getting an out of stock order from Amazon side. Actually we are updating the inventory hourly for example at 9:05, 10:05, 11:05, etc but using this approach for number of times we get an out of stock order. I can explain it as suppose there is a product having quantity 1 at our end and this quantity has been updated at Amazon but just after the updating the inventory at 10:20 on our side it gets ordered & goes out of stock but it is still showing in stock on Amazon and as a result of which customers are able to place order this product. When we import this order at our end we find this product as out of stock & we need to cancel this order & it affects performance & ratings. Therefore we want to prevent by using some approach which can provide to update inventory instantly.

We use the _POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_ feed type when updating inventory.

Additionally we are using PHP language.

Any suggestion & solution will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is astonishingly simple: If you're running out of stock, don't wait for the next update cycle (the wall clock hitting *:05 again), but send an inventory update right away. Since you're posting the inventory, it is *your* choice when to do it.

Just a side note: You probably will need to limit those updates in some way so that you don't send inventory updates more often than about every 5 minutes, otherwise they'll queue up (in my testing at least). Queued inventory updates won't do you any good.